# sum of row in the same columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe something like this

```
   d1  d2    d3    d4
  780  37.0  21.4  122840.0
  784  38.1  21.4  122860.0
  846  38.1  21.4  122880.0
  843  38.0  21.5  122900.0
  820  36.3  22.9  133220.0
  819  36.3  22.9  133240.0
  819  36.4  22.9  133260.0
  820  36.3  22.9  133280.0
  822  36.4  22.9  133300.0
```

how do i get the sum of values between the same column in a new column in a dataframe
for example:

```
 d1    d2    d3    d4       d5 
780  37.0  21.4  122840.0  1564
784  38.1  21.4  122860.0  1630
846  38.1  21.4  122880.0  1689
```

i want a new column with the sum of d1[i] + d1[i+1] .i know .sum() in pandas but i cant do sum between the same column

Comment: `df['d1'] + df['d1'].shift(-1)`.

Comment: Your expected output is just the first `3` rows of your `df`, is this right?

Comment: @QuangHoang its just concated the first row with the second it doesnt add

Comment: @user123 check your data type. Are they integer or string?

Comment: @MayankPorwal No i am expecting the sum of row until the last index in the dataframe. i just shorten the df for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not fully clear to me, but I think what you mean to do is:

```py
df['d5'] = df['d1'] + df['d1'].shift(-1)
```

Now you have to decide what you want to happen for the last element of the series.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `rolling`

```
df['d5'] = df['d1'].rolling(2 ,min_periods=1).sum()
df
Out[321]: 
    d1    d2    d3        d4      d5
0  780  37.0  21.4  122840.0   780.0
1  784  38.1  21.4  122860.0  1564.0
2  846  38.1  21.4  122880.0  1630.0
3  843  38.0  21.5  122900.0  1689.0
4  820  36.3  22.9  133220.0  1663.0
5  819  36.3  22.9  133240.0  1639.0
6  819  36.4  22.9  133260.0  1638.0
7  820  36.3  22.9  133280.0  1639.0
8  822  36.4  22.9  133300.0  1642.0
```